# Как массово создать в каждой папке папку и переместить в нее содержимое папки?

Tags: bash

есть 100 папок вида:

```
папка1\файлы и папки
папка2\файлы и папки
папка3\файлы и папки
...
```

подскажите как массово создать в каждой папке папку с названием "folder" и перенести в нее содержиое этой папки,
чтобы получилось :

```
папка1\folder\файлы и папки
папка2\folder\файлы и папки
папка3\folder\файлы и папки
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если эти 100 папок имеют определённый формат имени или находятся в каталоге, где больше ничего нет, то можно использовать такой вариант:

```
for i in *; do mv "$i" folder && mkdir "$i" && mv folder "$i"/; done
```

Было:

```
$ ls -lhFAQ *
"папка1":
итого 8,0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 mah69k mah69k 4,0K сен 22 12:25 "папка11"/
drwxr-xr-x 2 mah69k mah69k 4,0K сен 22 12:25 "папка12"/
-rw-r--r-- 1 mah69k mah69k    0 сен 22 12:25 "файл11"

"папка 2":
итого 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 mah69k mah69k 0 сен 22 12:25 "файл21"
-rw-r--r-- 1 mah69k mah69k 0 сен 22 12:25 "файл 22"

"папка3":
итого 4,0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 mah69k mah69k 4,0K сен 22 12:25 "папка 31"/
```

Стало:

```
$ ls -lhFAQ *
"папка1":
итого 4,0K
drwxr-xr-x 4 mah69k mah69k 4,0K сен 22 12:25 "folder"/

"папка 2":
итого 4,0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 mah69k mah69k 4,0K сен 22 12:25 "folder"/

"папка3":
итого 4,0K
drwxr-xr-x 3 mah69k mah69k 4,0K сен 22 12:25 "folder"/

$ ls -lhFAQ */*
"папка1/folder":
итого 8,0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 mah69k mah69k 4,0K сен 22 12:25 "папка11"/
drwxr-xr-x 2 mah69k mah69k 4,0K сен 22 12:25 "папка12"/
-rw-r--r-- 1 mah69k mah69k    0 сен 22 12:25 "файл11"

"папка 2/folder":
итого 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 mah69k mah69k 0 сен 22 12:25 "файл21"
-rw-r--r-- 1 mah69k mah69k 0 сен 22 12:25 "файл 22"

"папка3/folder":
итого 4,0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 mah69k mah69k 4,0K сен 22 12:25 "папка 31"/
```

Comment: Да, формат имени этих ста папок один - это названия сайтов вида: "site.ru", "site.com", "site.net". И находятся в каталоге в котором больше ничего нет

Comment: @Новичёк: тогда звёздочки в качестве маски будет достаточно.